# jQuery Duplicate Class Names Causing Multiple Toggles

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the below code to toggle an element.  The problem is the class name .item-options appears on the page multiple times and this causes the toggle to fire multiple times every time the element is clicked.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("ul.item-options").click(function (evt) {
        if(evt.target.tagName != 'UL')
            return;
        jQuery("li", this).toggle(500);
    });
});
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: The behaviour you describe should not be possible; the `click` only ever fires on the element which was clicked, not random elements with the same class. Please add an example of your HTML to the question

Comment: To see what I mean, check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xm4vzrh6). Note that you have to click to the left of the dot, due to your `tagName != 'UL'` condition

Comment: That must be due to another JS code causing conflicts.